# run build for vue.js on cent os 7.5 sh: vue-cli-service: command not found

Tags: vue.js, centos7

I got vue command working status:

```
[root@example.com vue-ts-starter]# vue
Usage: vue <command> [options]

Options:
  -V, --version  output the version number
  -h, --help     output usage information

Commands:
  init           generate a new project from a template
  list           list available official templates
  build          prototype a new project
  create         (for v3 warning only)
  help [cmd]     display help for [cmd]
```

On try :

```
vue build
```

I got:

We are slimming down vue-cli to optimize the initial installation by removing the `vue build` command.
Check out Poi (https://github.com/egoist/poi) which offers the same functionality!

On

```
  npm run build
```

(On my local computer everything works fine)
This is error log :

```
> vue-cli-service build

sh: vue-cli-service: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! vue-ts-starter@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
```

Comment: First, it looks like you've installed an old version of Vue CLI. You should use `npm install -g @vue/cli`. Second, have you installed your project's dependencies with `npm install` (run from the project directory)?

Comment: Yes i do it just like that.

Comment: I need env path to be setup in correct way...